# Textarea typing issue in ngFor in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have a list of questions inside in one Array.So am using ngFor to display the questions.To answer question i have textarea control which is also ngFor. The problem is if i trying to answer one question by typing the same text appears in all answer textarea.How to fix this?

Html:

```
    <li class="media media-sm" *ngFor="let question of test.Questions">
    <h5 class="media-heading">{{ question.Description }}? </h5>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea rows="3" name="answer" [(ngModel)]="postAnswer.Description" class="form-control bg-silver" placeholder="Answer Here..."
        ngModel #answer="ngModel"></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!postAnswer.Description" type="submit" (click)="addNewAnswer(question.QuestionID)">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
    </li>
```

Typescript:

```
async addNewAnswer(questionId: number) {
      this.postAnswer.QuestionID = questionId;
let response = <HttpResponse<Object>>await this.answerService.postAnswer(this.postAnswer);
}
```

Models:

```
 export class Test {
    property 1: string;
    Questions: Question[];
    }

    export class Question {
    property 1: string;
    QuestionId: number;
    Answer: Answer;
    }

    export class Answer{
    property 1: string;
    QuestionId: number;
    Description: string;
    }
```

When i post answer the answer added to corresponding question but the problem is typing issue. I tried all the solutions don't mark it as duplicate question the solution for the related questions is not fixing my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You bind all data into: `[(ngModel)]=postAnswer.Description` so text appears in all textareas. You should add some kind of filter with ID of textarea, or use array to keep all textareas, like `[(ngModel)]=postAnswer[id].Description`;

The simplest working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yyvqvg?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

For this idea you need:
in your **component.ts**

```
public tempVal = {};
public addNewAnswer(id, value) {
   console.log('ID', id);
   console.log("VAL", value);
}
```

and in your component.html

```
<li class="media media-sm" *ngFor="let question of test; let i = index;">
    <textarea rows="3" name="answer" [(ngModel)]="tempVal[i]" class="form-control bg-silver" placeholder="Answer Here..."
        ngModel #answer="ngModel"></textarea>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="addNewAnswer(question, tempVal[i])">BUTTON</button>
</li>
```

Comment: If i gave like that my UI not loading properly.Only one textarea is appearing and in the console an error saying Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined

Comment: It means that you have wrong implementation of this solutions. For example you can create `obj` for all textareas. If you click 'answer' button and open new textarea you can push into `postAnswer` `id` of your answer, and use it at this time. Of course you need also `*ngIf` to prevent usage of `undefined` `postAnswer[id]`.

Comment: I don't have id for answer.Using QuestionId only i can answer for any question that's why i passed the questionid in button click

Comment: What condition to give NgIf?

Comment: `*ngIf=postAnswer[id]`, but I think that you don't have good concept for this task. You need to know for which one object you want push the answer, without this data you can't connect question and answer together.

Comment: Ok i will check

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample code for your example.
Please check below link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cahh4l

On clicking submit, the answer is logged in console.
Please let me know if you have any queries.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Define postAnswers array

```
postAnswers: []
```

Then you need to map the postAnswers array to question array in that way that each postAnswer contains description and questionID. Do this after getting your test data.

```
postAnswers = test.Questions.map(q => return {
     QuestionID : q.QuestionID,
     description: ''
})
```

After that you need to bind one textarea to one postAnswer.
Also logic in button element should be different. Now disabled property should be binded to specific postAnswer element from the array and addNewAnswer method needs index instead of questionID .

```
<li class="media media-sm" *ngFor="let question of test.Questions;let i = index">
    <h5 class="media-heading">{{ question.Description }}? </h5>
    <div class="input-group">
        <textarea rows="3" name="answer" [(ngModel)]="postAnswers[i].Description" class="form-control bg-silver" placeholder="Answer Here..."
        ngModel #answer="ngModel"></textarea>
        <span class="input-group-append">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!postAnswers[i].Description" type="submit" (click)="addNewAnswer(i)">
    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
    </li>
```

And finally modify your addNewAnswer method to this:

```
async addNewAnswer(index: number) {
let response = <HttpResponse<Object>>await this.answerService.postAnswer(this.postAnswer[index]);
}
```

This should work

Comment: I can't declare postAnswers as array. Because there is only one answer posted at a time. Each question have only one answer if we want the existing answer can be edited. Am not mentioning that functions here because its all working

Comment: `this.answerService.postAnswer(this.postAnswer[index]);` - I am posting one answer at a time, but I keep track of all answers localy. Your code binds one answer to all questions, that's why when you type in one textarea, the text appears in all.

Comment: It is still the same, your code binds one textarea to all questions, you need one textarea per question

Comment: As mentioned by @DusanRadovanovic you need to use indexing for ngModel to differentiate between answers for the questions. 
Else all your questions will point to a single answer which is held by postAnswer.Description.